# Array formula to show a leading zero

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a Google Sheet where an array formula in Column `I` creates a video name based on the content entered into columns `A+B+C+D`.
Column `C` is the number of the video. For some videos, I need a leading zero in the name and for others, not. I don't want to format column `C` as text - I need to leave this column formatted as a number. I also had to format Column `C` to add a full stop after the number as it is important this is part of the number in the name. I can't rely on editors to always remember to add the full stop.

What do I add to the array formula so it correctly reflects the content in Column `C`, where some videos will have a leading zero (like 01. and some not, like 0.)

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($E2:$E="Yes", $D2:$D, IF(ISBLANK($A2:$A), "", $A2:$A & " - ") & IF(ISBLANK($B2:$B), "", $B2:$B & " - ") & IF(ISBLANK($C2:$C), "", $C2:$C & ". ") & $D2:$D))`

Here is my Google Test Sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AIdZmFqtojG_7OLY_twJhmFewVTyoFAsozzbeSeHun4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either the following formulas instead

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($E2:$E="Yes", $D2:$D, IF(ISBLANK($A2:$A), "", $A2:$A & " - ") & IF(ISBLANK($B2:$B), "", $B2:$B & " - ") & IF(ISBLANK($C2:$C), "", TEXT($C2:$C,"00. ")) & $D2:$D))
```

OR

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($E2:$E="Yes", $D2:$D, IF(ISBLANK($A2:$A), "", $A2:$A & " - ") & IF(ISBLANK($B2:$B), "", $B2:$B & " - ") & IF(ISBLANK($C2:$C), "", TEXT($C2:$C,"00") & ". ") & $D2:$D))
```

*(Either of the above formulas will format all single digit numbers in column `C` having a leading `0`. This will provide even better consistency to your results than the one you are asking for, as in "Big battles! - 01. Bass drum" instead of "Big battles! - 1. Bass drum")*

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this formula forces all the videos to have a leading zero. Not all videos are supposed to have a leading zero. Only those where there is a leading zero in Column C.

Comment: We only use leading zeros where there is a collection of videos in excess of 9.

Comment: This note is at the top of the column in my test sheet - How do I change the array formula so it reflects the formatting of the number in column C? For example, The Arts Unit @home Creative Classes - Introduced Species - 1. Interview with Katy Abbott should have a zero in front of the 1 so it displays as 01. rather than 1. Not all videos have a leading zero, only those idenfitied in column C with a leading zero should have a leading zero.

Comment: I am afraid you will not be able to accomplish that without manual intervention. That is you cannot have only *some* videos display the leading zero. To enjoy the benefits of automation you need to slightly divert from your way of naming the videos. Also, as mentioned in my answer, I think it is a more consistent way of naming them. Things can get really messy down the line. Please trust me on that. I have been archiving masses of work for years.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I agree with you but unfortunately, I don't have a say in this convention. I won't be able to manually change the data appearing in column I with the array formula as it is copied from the top down. I think in this case I will simply have to change column C to a text column. This will ensure column I with the array formula displays the data as required. This spreadsheet exists to help editors name videos. Now that I think about it, once the video is named it moves into another Excel sheet where the numbers become part of the name and are only read as text anyway.

Comment: Though we took a long turn, you finally came up with the right solution. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos I was wondering if there was any way you could look at my latest question called Conditional formatting using VLOOKUP - need help. This is the last big issue in my spreadsheet puzzle for now.

Comment: The question is here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142392/conditional-formatting-using-vlookup-need-help